# Is there a proper way to create a constructor?

Tags: constructor

Is there a proper way to create a constructor? What would be a "nice" code?

```
namespace Fahrzeuge
{
    class UsedCars
    {
        public int Wheels { get; set; }

        public string Model { get; set; }

       public UsedCars(int wheels, string model)
        {
            Wheels = wheels;
            Model = model;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] and tag a language. Looks like [tag:C#].

Comment: Also, your question is unclear. What does "the right way" mean? Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your needs.

[Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) typically are used to initialize new instance of a class.

In your example you created class `UsedCars` with only one constructor accepting two arguments, so user of your class will be obliged to pass that two arguments, example: `new UsedCars(4, "Tesla")`. Is that what you want?

Just in case if you would like to give user an option to initialize properties of the object without forcing him to pass them via constructor you can just use ["object initializer"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer) feature of C# language, example: `new UsedCars { Wheels = 4 }`

Finally, looks like your class is POCO-like, if so then you can use ["records"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) feature of C# language, that case your class can be rewritten just with single line `record UsedCars(int Wheels, string Model)`

So, first of all try to think about purpose of the class, how it will be used and how would you like it to behave.